# Aggregate related query in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a question related with aggregate function.

For now, I want to do some average based on 2 tables. 1st table is the criteria table, it include the criteria for each scenario. 2nd table is the data table, it include the all the records need to be used for average.

Following are the structure of 2 tables.

**Table 1: category**

```
CREATE TABLE Sales
(
SaleDate date,
SalerZip varchar(255),
ProductID integer,
AveragePrice integer
);

Create table details
(
ListSaleDate date,
SalerZip varchar(255),
buyerDistance integer,
price integer,
ProductID integer
);
```

Note, it is auction price, so, same product can be sold with different price.

The requirement is as following. For each record in table category (A), we need to search in table details (B) for a bunch of records which fit the following criteria

1. A.SaleDate - 30 days <= B.date < A.SaleDate
2. A.ProductID = B.ProductID
3. A.SalerZip = B.SalerZip and B.buyerDistance < 200

So, for each record in table A, we can find a group of records from table B, the average price for this group of records in table B will be saved into table A column AveragePrice.

Comment: where is your attempt ??

Comment: post your code of what you have tried

Comment: For the record, storing data based on data in related tables is a bad design.  You should create a `VIEW` that calculates that data, otherwise you have to constantly update it.

Comment: Also post an example required output

Comment: It's not clear why you have `ProductID` on the sales table either.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the result in a field in the `Sales` table, otherwise you need to recalculate the result every time the details change.  You should create a view for this:

```
CREATE VIEW SalesView
AS
SELECT 
    SaleDate date,
    SalerZip varchar(255),
    A.ProductID,
    AVG(B.Price) AveragePrice
FROM Sales A
INNER JOIN Details B
ON DATEDIFF(Day,A.SaleDate, -30) <= B.ListSaleDate
    AND B.ListSaleDate < A.SaleDate
    AND A.ProductID = B.ProductID
    AND A.SalerZip = B.SalerZip and B.buyerDistance < 200
GROUP BY A.SaleDate,
    A.SalerZip,
    A.ProductID
```

Comment: It not work. The Group by does not working. I queried in SAS SQL, it will give multiple records, seems that the Group by does not work.